# Kubuntu 18.04 freezes during install

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, 19.04, lock-screen

I have an HP with Intel i5 and integrated graphics. Install always goes almost all the way through and freezes at 94%.

So I installed Kubuntu 16.04 and tried to update to 18 and it makes it nearly all the way through and then has a message:

> The screen locker is broken and no longer functions.

So then I tried installing Kubuntu 19.04 and also freezes during install. Had no problems with installing Kubuntu 16.04, and also had Linux Mint 18.2 previously and it installed immediately.

I spent probably 9 hours trying to get any form of Ubuntu installed KDE, MATE, Gnome all `failed.Sfailed.Secureboot` is off tried all these installs in both legacy and UEFI.

Comment: Please provide some more information. From your observation with the 94% completion, it could be that `grub-install` is failing. With Ctrl+Alt+F2...7 you can open the installer log or the shell. Checkout `cat /var/log/syslog` for any error messages.

Comment: The message `The screen locker is broken and no longer functions.` is unrelated and is due to the fact that 16.04 and 18.04 use a different screen locker process, so until reboot the screen locker will not function again.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it to work as an update from Kubuntu 16. In legacy mode with lock screen turned off, as well as all power saver functions.Then I used the update from the menu,then did konsole update for 18.04. I was actually surprised,figured I was gonna have endless rolling text when I got home.